# Handling multiple id in jquery and update only input of same id

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is my code that i use for autocomplete (from php db I get id and name)

```
<input type="text" id="rubrica_1"><input type="hidden" id="value_1">
<input type="text" id="rubrica_2"><input type="hidden" id="value_2">
<input type="text" id="rubrica_3"><input type="hidden" id="value_3">
```

Then script is

```
  $( '[id^=rubrica_]' ).autocomplete({
    source:'content/json/autocomplete.php', 
    minLength:2,
    select: function(event,ui){
      $( '[id^=value_]').val(ui.item.id);
    }
  });
```

With this solution I update all value_1, value_2 and value_3 with same val...

Comment: Are you able to change the html?  If you can, I'd add a `data-` attribute to pair them, eg `<input type="text" id="rubrica_1" data-in="1"><input type="hidden" id="value_1" data-in="1">` then your final line can be `$("input:hidden[data-in='" + $(this).data("in") + "']").val(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` in select function which refers to targeted input element. along with next selector to target next hidden input:

```
$( '[id^=rubrica_]' ).autocomplete({
source:'content/json/autocomplete.php', 
minLength:2,
select: function(event,ui){
   $(this).next().val(ui.item.id);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for allocate value to same elements

```
<input type="text" id="rubrica_1"><input class="same_id" type="hidden" id="value_1">
<input type="text" id="rubrica_2"><input class="same_id" type="hidden" id="value_2">
<input type="text" id="rubrica_3"><input class="same_id" type="hidden" id="value_3">

$( '[id^=rubrica_]' ).autocomplete({
source:'content/json/autocomplete.php', 
minLength:2,
select: function(event,ui){
  $( '.same_id').val(ui.item.id);
}
 });
```

Comment: This would affect all the hidden input elements.